# Unable to update Google App on Nexus 6P running Android N Developer Preview

Tags: uninstallation, 7.0-nougat

A few weeks ago I installed Google App version **5.14.15.NYC.21.arm64** on my Nexus 6P running Android N Developer Preview 3. Now this app is not getting any updates from the Play Store and not letting me install any of its update in the usual method.

If I try, it gives me an error saying:

"The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name".

I tried through adb using:

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR].
```

The newest version of this app is version 6.0.17.21. Also there is no option coming up on the phone to uninstall this update. What should I do?

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: Nope, I didn't root my phone, just opted in for the beta program of the app...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. My Nexus 6P also runs the developer preview and has this version: `5.14.15.NYC.21.arm64`.

The reason it won't update is because the actual version code is higher then the one on Google Play. That's because it is targeted to Android N.

I wouldn't recommend you to install the version on Google Play, because it probably will keep crashing because of no Android N support.

---

In the following screenshot you can see the app has a very high **Version Code** and the **Target SDK** is set to 10000. (=Developer preview)

[image: screenshot]

<sub>(Click image for larger version)</sub>